# Camera Solving, the trackers in 3D space are inverted

Tags: camera, tracking

I have a shot I'm tracking and the problem is that after I hit *Setup Tracking Scene*, I check the points in the *3D viewport* and the trackers that are supposed to be in the distant background are closest to the camera and the trackers that were tracked in the foreground of my footage is farthest from the camera in 3D space; it's somehow inverted.

I set the origin and floor markers.

I'd appreciate any help. Thanks!

[image]

Dropbox link to Footage Sequence and .Blend file: 
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/vbzan9by8p8dp1f/AABu2wP8uSUodfdhIFt8a7q7a?dl=0

Comment: Can you go to _File > External Data_ and select _Automatically Pack Into .blend_ and then upload your .blend file to [Blend Exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com)?

Comment: Your solve error is? Please read: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/42332/3710

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more information, include a few images that can help us understand the trajectory in which the camera is moving.  To better help you please consider uploading the video segment and your blend file and sharing the link.

Comment: @ShadyPuck packing will not save the video file as part of the blend.

Comment: Thanks for the repy.   See how the tree marker is close to the camera

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get better results when doing camera motion tracking?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42329/how-can-i-get-better-results-when-doing-camera-motion-tracking)

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem. The points closer to the horizon were solved to be the closest point to the camera. That was when I was using auto detected points. I started over and manually selected a lot of high contrast point, only kept the good ones after looking at the graph clip editor, and then the scene solved perfectly